# Telerik Reporting Failed to connect to server

Tags: telerik-reporting

Using ODP.NET managed provider, I'm trying to connect telerik reporting tool to an oracle database on a remote server but I keep getting this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0tWz.png)

Even though it works just fine when tryin to connect to a database on my local machine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPx7z.png)

Also the sql developer can connect to the database on the remote server with no issues

Can anyone help me to fix it?

I tried to add a tns name in the tnsnames.ora and I tried to add a listener in the listener.ora file but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Given that the error is thrown by the Oracle Managed Driver itself, I guess the problem is not related to the Telerik Report Designer, but rather to a network issue. The Reporting engine is database-agnostic and doesn't "know" to which database it connects. It instantiates a [IDbConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idbconnection) from the Oracle DbProviderFactory, passes the connection string, and tries to open a connection.

Check if you're able to connect to the **/civil** data source from a standalone app, providing the same connection string. If the connection fails, inspect the network settings (firewall, incoming IP whitelists, etc.).